# OS X frequent crash. printer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, debugging, printing

I usually don't use OS X because I run a linux partition. Been needing to access xcode so I've been using it again. It just shuts off all of a sudden and reboots. It seems like it does it more often with my printer plugged into USB. I'm running Mint and Blag on it, but I have never had any issues when running on those OSs even with the printer plugged in. Anyone make heads or tales of this stack?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  17556 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    6DA1700F-1927-B6CB-7922-15F95FA2CC21

Wed Sep 11 18:42:32 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80292ac90b): Releasing non-exclusive RW lock without a reader    refcount!
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8119993820 : 0xffffff802921d626 
0xffffff8119993890 : 0xffffff80292ac90b 
0xffffff81199938b0 : 0xffffff802931c09c 
0xffffff8119993ae0 : 0xffffff8029308fab 
0xffffff8119993b90 : 0xffffff80292fbb49 
0xffffff8119993c40 : 0xffffff80292fc314 
0xffffff8119993f50 : 0xffffff80295e182a 
0xffffff8119993fb0 : 0xffffff80292ced33 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: installd

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-    2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000029000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8029200000
System model name: Macmini5,1 (Mac-8ED6AF5B48C039E1)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 508482133713
last loaded kext at 31448390032: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr    0xffffff7faaa92000, size 36864)
last unloaded kext at 102515839551: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7fa9b17000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.5d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: Macmini5,1, BootROM MM51.0077.B10, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB,  SMC 1.76f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A54463531323634485A2D3147344D31
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A54463531323634485A2D3147344D31
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xE4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384, 500.11 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: USB Receiver, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc52b, 0xfd130000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: HP LaserJet 3050, 0x03f0  (Hewlett Packard), 0x3217, 0xfa130000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8281, 0xfa113000 / 7
```

Comment: You are asking what causes your computer to shut off?  If so, I'm afraid you are at a wrong place.

Comment: @TBlue It only does it in OSX so I don't think it's a hardware issue. Where would be the appropriate place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to 10.8.4 and problem solved. This solution came from Apple Support, apparently 10.8.2 commonly has this issue. Although I dislike forced updates, this solution worked.